# Entity Framework How to bind textbox to model in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Using Entity data model in a Windows Forms Project, I want to bind simultaneously Orders entity  to datagridview and to textBox, and textBox has to display OrderID value depending on the current line in the datagrid.

The code I used in Form load event is next:

```
    using(NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities())
    {
    ordersDataGridView.DataSource = context.Orders;
    OrderNumberTextBox.   ...
    }
```

For this case, what is the right syntax to bind Textbox ?  Thank you.

Comment: textBox haven't datasource so you should to bind it by your hand

Comment: I did not said textBox have datasource property, my question is how to make it show the field value? This text box had been dragged and dropped  from datasource window to the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind a `BindingSource` object to your `context.Orders`, bind your `DataGridView` to the `BindingSource`, and then through the [`TextBox.DataBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) property, bind to appropriate property of your `TextBox` to your `BindingSource`. The [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h974h4y2.aspx) object will manage the currency state so that the TextBox will change when you select different items in your DataGridView.

The binding will look similar to something to this:

```
OrderNumberTextBox.DataBindings("Text", bindingSource, "OrderID");
```